# Firestore security rule for FieldValue.increment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've a counter in firestore that count likes. And I increment it like [this](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-increment-tips/#:~:text=Firestore%20Increment,does%20all%20the%20calculation%20serverside.):

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();
const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

// Document reference
const doc = db.collection('coll').doc('doc');

// Update read count
doc.update({ likes: increment });
```

So if someone edits the source and replaces `increment` with `decrement`, it's going to work that way. I'd like to prevent that.

How can I write a [firestore-security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) rule for this so that the rule only allows incrementing and not decrementing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ensure that the new value is greater than the previous value with a [Security Rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) like the following one:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.likes > resource.data.likes;
```

---

BTW, note that [FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue) does not have a `decrement()` method. If you want to decrement, you need to use a negative number:

```
const decrement = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1);
```

Answer (score 12):

And if you want to enforce an increment by 1:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.likes == resource.data.likes + 1;
```

Comment: This will not work well if multiple users increase the same resource field at the same time.

Comment: It will work just as specified: each update has to increase the field "likes" by 1

Comment: @l1b3rty In other words this comment: "This will not work well if multiple users increase the same resource field at the same time. " then does not apply. Correct?

Comment: It may not work well but not because of the rule. There is a Firestore limitation at 1 write/sec on the same doc for instance, https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document

Comment: @l1b3rty I assume the 1write/sec soft limitation still applies even if it is an increment, even if the order of the requests do not matter.  If so, is there a way to queue the increment updates from various clients?

Comment: @ChristopherHaas Check this if you need more frequent updates: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: @ChristopherHaas the documentation doesn't indicate that writes are blocked beyond 1 / second, just that latency increases. I think the assumption is that the writes are queued

Comment: @GabrielGarrett, they are not queued and may fail over the specified limit, check the ling I provided for a solution